# Why is my check for when a function argument is not of a given type not working?

Tags: python, function

I have a very simple function, which takes as input a string, I tried to put a check on the function so that if the function **arguments** is not a **string** it will throw an error, else return the **string**.

The problem right now is that, when I pass an `int`, I expect the function to display an error but it simply outputs a tuple of `int`. What am I getting wrong here?

```
def speak(*languages):

    """Function takes a set of langs as input  and returns a list of languages"""
    
    try:
        if  type(languages) ==  str:
            languages = list(languages)
    except TypeError as error:
        print(error, ' You need to pass in the right datatype')
    else:
        return languages
```

I also tried this.

```
def speak(*languages):

    """Function takes a set of langs as input  and returns a list of languages"""
    
    try:
        if  isinstance(languages, str):
            languages = list(languages)
    except TypeError as error:
        print(error, ' You need to pass in the right datatype')
    else:
        return languages
```

I am calling the **speak** function the following ways.

1. speak('english') - expected output should be `english`
2. speak('english', 'french') - expected output should be `english` and `french`
3. speak(34) -  I expect the function to throw an error

Comment: `languages` will be a list, not a string, by the way.

Comment: @mkrieger1 A tuple, not a list.

Comment: Give an example of how you’re calling `speak()` - i.e. show the parameter(s) you’re passing

Comment: Why the asterisk in `*languages` ? As others commented, you should show how you are calling your function and what is the expected output for each case.

Comment: @Carlos I just updated the question with the ways I am calling the function and the expected output

Comment: @SvenEberth even when I don't convert the `languages` to a `list` the function behaves the same way

Comment: @Carlos I used the `args *` so that I can pass in multiple languages like this. `speak('english', 'french')`. what do you get as an output when you make a call to the function using the above arguments?

Comment: @ChukwukaOkolie I edited my question below. Test cases seems to be doing what they are supposed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you provided your example calls, it looks like you want to check **all** arguments for string-type and not one argument. Right?

You can use `any` for that, which will be True if any of the list/generator value is true. In the generator comprehension you can perform the `isinstance` over all (positional) arguments

```
def speak(*languages):
    """Function takes a set of langs as input  and returns a list of languages"""
    
    if any(not isinstance(lang, str) for lang in languages):
        raise TypeError('You need to pass in the right datatype')

    return list(languages)
```

```
>>> speak('english')
>>> speak('english', 'french')
>>> speak(34)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in speak
TypeError: You need to pass in the right datatype
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a try-except is needed here. Maybe try something like this (following your reasoning):

```
def speak(*languages):

    """Function takes a set of langs as input  and returns a list of languages"""
    for lang in list(languages):
        if not isinstance(lang, str):
            print(' You need to pass in the right datatype')
            return
    else:
        languages = list(languages)
        return languages

print(speak('english')) # english
print(speak('english', 'french')) # english and french
print(speak(34)) # error
```

Comment: passing a string as an argument to the above function executes the `else`  statement. which shouldn't be the case. I expect the `if` statement to pass in such condition

Comment: @ChukwukaOkolie Edited the answer with your test cases

Answer (score -1):

Neither `type(languages) == str` nor `isinstance(languages, str)` will throw a `TypeError`, so your `except` will never be hit.  You simply need an `else` after your `if`:

```
def speak(*languages):
    """Function takes a set of langs as input and returns a list of languages"""

    if isinstance(languages, str):
        return list(languages)
    else:
        raise TypeError('You need to pass in the right datatype')
```

Note: I don't think you want `list(languages)` above - `list("a str")` gives `['a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r']`.  But I left it because it's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't actually throwing an error here, to do so, you need to use `raise`:

```py
def speak(*languages):

    """Function takes a set of langs as input  and returns a list of languages"""
    
    if  isinstance(languages, str):
        languages = list(languages)
        
    else:
        raise TypeError('You need to pass in the right datatype')
        
    return languages
```

Comment: The above function throws an error when I pass in str as an argument which shouldn't be the expected behaviour

Comment: I tried your solution using `speak('english')` and `speak(50)`. the two function calls throws an error. I expect 1 to pass and 2 to fail